# Read a string in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a question regarding to my project which is how to read a string in AS3.

Actually, I have an text file named test.txt. For instance:

It consists of:
 Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat

and then I want to put all of them into an array and then a string to show them in the dynamic text Box called text_txt:

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
 var days:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
 var str:String;
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, arrayToString);

 function arrayToString(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
    for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++)
    {
        str = days.join("");
        text_txt.text = str + "\n" + ";"; //it does not work here
    }
 }
}

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("test.txt"));
```

BUT IT DOES NOT show them in different line and then put a ";" at the end of each line !

I can make it to show them in different line, but I need to put them in different line in txt file and also I still do not get the ";" at the end of each line unless put it in the next file also at the end of each line.

And then I want to read the string and show an object from my library based on each word or line. for example:

```
//I  do not know how to write it or do we have a function to read a string and devide it to the words after each space or line 
if (str.string="sun"){
 show(obj01);
}
if (str.string="mon"){
 show(obj02);
}
```

I hope I can get the answer for this question.
Please inform me if you can not get the concept of the last part. I will try to explain it more until you can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: the second part is unclear, can you tell it in FARSI?  what is `str.string="mon"` !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must enable multiline ability for your `TextField` (if did not)

---

### adobe As3 DOC :

> **join()** Converts the elements in an array to strings, inserts the
>   specified separator between the elements, concatenates them, and
>   returns the resulting string. A nested array is always separated by a
>   comma (,), not by the separator passed to the join() method.

---

so `str = days.join("");` converts the Array to a single string, and as your demand ( parameter passed to join is empty "") there is no any thing between fetched lines. and `text_txt.text = str + "\n" + ";";` only put a ***new line*** at the end of the text once.

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var days:Array;

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    days = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
    var str:String;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, arrayToString);
}

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("test.txt"));


function arrayToString(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    text_txt.multiline = true;
    text_txt.wordWrap = true;
    text_txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    text_txt.text = days.join("\n");
}
```

<sup>also i moved `arrayToString` out of onLoaded</sup>

for second Question: to checking existance of a word, its better using `indexOf("word")` instead comparing it with "==" operator, because of invisible characters like "\r" or "\n".

```
if (str.indexOf("sun") >= 0){
    show(obj01);
}
if (str.indexOf("mon") >= 0){
    show(obj02);
}
```

Comment: did you try it in your side? It does not work for me!

Comment: This is what I can get exactly in the out put:  sun,mon,tue,wed,thr,fri,sat

Comment: @Maziar the preferred code is tested and correct in regular cases, i don't know what is wrong in your text field. i'll test it by a "text.txt" file now.

Comment: @Maziar every thing is OK, tested with text file too, nothing wrong, i'll add the answer of last part soon. if you still have problem with this solution, please test it one time in a new project, with only one textfield at main timeline, then you see it works

Comment: payam I can write each day in one line in my test.txt and then show them in different line in the output. BUT, read the string is the main problem. I can send to you my file if you have any email or...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130317/discussion-between-payam-sbr-and-maziar).

Comment: @Maziar i just invited you in a chat, join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130317/discussion-between-payam-sbr-and-maziar

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first part:

```
for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++)
    {
        str = days[i];
        text_txt.text += str + ";" + "\n";
    }
```

I hope I understand you correctly..
I wrote from memory, sorry for typos if there are...

For the second part, add a switch-case

```
switch(str) {
     case "sun":
           Show(??);
           break;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: the correct one is : str = days[i]; text_txt.appendText (str + ";" + "\n"); and the output is not correct as the ";" will be shown at the beginning of next line:(.

Comment: @Maziar you can use str.substring(0, str.length-2) to exclude the line break. Maybe there is even a better method this is from my memory, and I don't sure about -2, maybe -1 better. I don't understand the second part of your question... I'll correct my answer when we fix all the problems =]